# YIi2 upload folder move to project root directory

Tags: .htaccess, upload, yii2

how to keep Files upload folder in root directory of project.
which change need in htaccess?

```
    Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^admin(.+)?$ backend/web/$1 [L,PT]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

currently my image files are store in 
project/backend/web/uploads/
i want to upload dynamic files in 
root folder of project ie project/uploadImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the project root directory  in advanced  template is two level upper the home directory for you application  .

then If you have proper right for this and need  an access to this level you could create an alias eg:

```
 Yii::setAlias('@my_project_home', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../'));
```

or if you want store in upload subdir of project directory

```
 Yii::setAlias('@my_project_upload', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../upload'));
```

you can retrive the alias using :

```
Yii::getAlias('@my_project_upload');  // displays: your_project/upload
```

see more for alias  here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html

Comment: i achieved by myself.